# porting java code to contiki-os

Tags: porting, contiki

i am using contiki-os to simulate some motes which would have semantic capabilities. As the contiki-os (erbium) is written in C but our semantic libraries are written in java.

can anyone here guide me if it is possible to exploit these libraries in erbium or contiki-os. or i have to rewrite everything from scratch ?

**update**

just a minor update to the question. is it possible to use java code on the cooja simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cooja is indeed written in Java.

You can extend or modify Cooja if you need.

You can find out more about Cooja on [the Contiki wiki](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/An-Introduction-to-Cooja) as well as in [numerous papres by Fredrik Österlind](http://scholar.google.se/citations?hl=en&user=c_vkgKoAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&pagesize=100). Perhaps you should also take a look at Fredrik's PhD thesis ["Improving Low-Power Wireless Protocols with Timing-Accurate Simulation"](http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:447343/FULLTEXT01), which is mostly about Cooja.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something like this:

```
http://www.codemesh.com/products/junction/
```

It appears to have a code generator that takes a java bytecode and create C code from it... but it might also need a runtime library that's platform specific.

With all that in mind, I don't think you will be successful. Most of the platforms are nearly out of space and/or flash by the time you are working with Erbuim; I doubt you'll have resources to process java code somehow.

And if you did get some success from this approach it would probably take a lot of time and effort to do so. With that time and effort you probably could have written the C code to do what you need instead.